# The system cannot find the file specified in sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['py', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\Scorpion\\Desktop\\Facial Recognition Python\\program.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\Scorpion\Desktop\Facial Recognition Python]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Go\bin;"C:\python35;";C:\Users\Scorpion\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Scorpion\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Scorpion\go\bin;C:\xampp\php;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;]
[Finished]
```

I am new to python and sublime text, I have written the whole program but it is not executed
Can somebody help!!

I am new to python and sublime text, I have written the whole program but it is not executed
Can somebody help!!

Comment: can you confirm that you are able to run a basic `hello world.py` example first ?

Comment: That error message happens when Windows can't find the thing that is being executed (in this case `py`); so first, make sure that you actually installed Python, and that when you did, you told it to install the `py` helper.